# wxWidgets: How to adjust size of indent of wxDataViewCtrl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using the Gtk port of wxWidgets 3.0.2.

I have a wxDataViewCtrl displaying it's data model in a tree-like fashion.  Is it possible to make the size of how much child nodes are indented underneath its parent node bigger?

I know there's a wxDataViewCtrl::SetIndent() method, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  Indeed, when I look at source code for SetIndent(), it calls out to a DoSetIndent() method and for Gtk, this method is actually a no-op :-(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is impossible, but it actually seems simple to do using [gtk_tree_view_set_level_indentation()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-level-indentation), so I've just [done this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/4379f599e8d5603e46fe16bcb511175fef19eb52) and `SetIndent()` will work in wxWidgets 3.1.0 to be released soon.

In the meanwhile, you can do the same thing in your own code using `wxWindow::GetHandle()` to retrieve `GtkTreeView` widget from the control.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work.  Although, calling GetHandle() on a wxDataViewCtrl apparently returns a GtkScrolledWindow rather than a GtkTreeView.  I had to call wxDataViewCtrl::GtkGetTreeView() instead.